# List Comprehension Returning Memory Position

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to extract information from the following data set formatted as a list where each news article is its own dictionary:

```
news_data = [{'source': {'id': 'the-verge', 'name': 'The Verge'}, 'author': 'Emma Roth', 'title': "Judge rules Tesla can't hide behind arbitration in sexual harassment case - The Verge", 'description': 'A lawsuit accusing Tesla of fostering a work environment with “rampant” sexual harassment will continue in court after a judge blocked Tesla’s request for arbitration.', 'url': 'https://www.theverge.com/2022/5/24/23140051/judge-rules-tesla-hide-behind-arbitration-sexual-harassment-case-elon-musk', 'urlToImage': 'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/t3DT8qyznxCW4ahGTwGCSC4l56s=/0x146:2040x1214/fit-in/1200x630/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/10752835/acastro_180430_1777_tesla_0001.jpg', 'publishedAt': '2022-05-24T22:16:03Z', 'content': 'Tesla cant dismiss this case so easily\r\nIllustration by Alex Castro / The Verge\r\nA lawsuit that accuses Tesla of fostering a workplace with rampant sexual harassment will continue in court after a Ca… [+2274 chars]'}, {'source': {'id': 'bloomberg', 'name': 'Bloomberg'}, 'author': None, 'title': 'Elon Musk Drops Out of $200 Billion Club Again as Tesla Tumbles - Bloomberg', 'description': None, 'url': 'https://www.bloomberg.com/tosv2.html?vid=&uuid=38abbf6a-dbe7-11ec-9ad9-767145594c47&url=L25ld3MvYXJ0aWNsZXMvMjAyMi0wNS0yNC9lbG9uLW11c2stZHJvcHMtb3V0LW9mLTIwMC1iaWxsaW9uLWNsdWItYWdhaW4tYXMtdGVzbGEtdHVtYmxlcw==', 'urlToImage': None, 'publishedAt': '2022-05-24T21:11:29Z', 'content': "To continue, please click the box below to let us know you're not a robot."}]
```

Specifically, I want to extract only the keys 'title' and 'description', saving them into a list for use later.

I've attempted to do this with the following list comprehension:

```py
news_info = [((k,v) for (k,v) in article if k in ['title', 'description']) for article in news_data]
```

However, if I print the result, I am simply informed:

```
[<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x102c27840>, <generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x102c26dc0>]
```

Furthermore, if I attempt to access information (e.g. `print(news_info[0]['title'])`) there is a "TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable".

I was wondering how I can go about printing and accessing/using the information that is saved in the list.

Comment: You are using generator expressions `(x for ..)`, not list comprehensions `[x for ..]`.

Comment: @timgeb both, actually

Comment: @matszwecja well, on the inner level, obviously

Comment: Remove `((k,v) for (k,v) in article if k in ['title', 'description'])` from its outer parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on the intend, but from what you've tried it seems like you are looking for the result that this should present you:

```py
news_info = [{'title': article['title'], 'description': article['description']} for article in news_data]
print(news_info[0]['title'])
```

I'd recommend using a function to create the dictionary though.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `()` inside the comprehension is creating a generator. If you're expecting a tuple to be created inside here, then just append the word tuple to the beginning.

```
news_info = [tuple((k,v) for (k,v) in article.items() ...
```

You also had an issue in that you need to be iterating over the article items.

Answer (score 0):

`((k,v) for (k,v) in article if k in ['title', 'description'])` - this piece of code creates *generator expression*. That's why you are getting generator objects.
Another mistake is that you are iterating over dictionary keys, not k,v pairs.
Taking both into account that is what it should look like:

```
news_info = [(k,v) for article in news_data for (k,v) in article.items() if k in ['title', 'description']]
```

Comment: This creates a flat list and loses the grouping that the op had if they'd expanded those generators

Comment: Wouldn't happen if question included *expected output*. I'm not going to try and figure out which exactly of different possibilities to store that data OP had in mind.